# Python : How to make different thread read different sections of my file

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a file with about 3 million lines. Each lines contains some data i would like to parse and post it to remote service call.

If i sequentially read the file it takes too long for the entire program to complete running.

I was thinking of starting a pool of thread each iterating on different lines of the file(for eg: thread 1 would read line 1 to 10, thread 2 line 11 to 20 and so on..), classic map/reduce problem. Is there a quick way to do this in python, any library that will help me with this task.

Comment: Are the lines all the same length, or at least predictable lengths?

Comment: Can I take it as order of the result doesn't have to be in correspondence with the order of the lines in the file?

Comment: they are not same length, but each line is delimited by a new character. its a tsv file with 3 fields.

Comment: @thefourtheye, that is right, order do not matter here. think as if all these lines need to be stored in a database.

Comment: I suggest you profile your existing code before attempting to optimize it. Depending on where it's spending most of it's time, multithreading may have no effect at all—or even make it slower.

Comment: Could you use one thread to read the file and `put` each line onto a `Queue` one line at a time, then have your worker threads `get` lines from that `Queue`?

Comment: You might want to go through http://effbot.org/zone/wide-finder.htm and [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) module.

Comment: Each thread could open the same file for independent reading. The tricky part for each would be deciding which part to read. Determining this would be each if the lines are all the same length, however if they are not would mean that each one would have to start at the beginning and skip over those it's not concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the file line by line, it 's not easy to do mutithreading with python. Because the seek() method needs to know the byte offset of each line.

An alternative is to split your file first, say using "split" on linux. Then start multiple threads to process the split files respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Because of GIL, multithreading may have no help for you. I think you may try multiprocess.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(lines):
    for l in lines:
        print l

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open('file')
    total = 2
    lines = f.readlines()
    step = lines/total
    p = Pool(total)
    p.map(f, [lines[0:step],lines[step:step*total-1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can write your own MapReduce according to your need.

See following code ([Source](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/mapreduce.html)). This code reads multiple file and generating output. You can modify your code such that each worker thread work with different segment of file.

```
import collections
import itertools
import multiprocessing

class SimpleMapReduce(object):

    def __init__(self, map_func, reduce_func, num_workers=None):
        """
        map_func

          Function to map inputs to intermediate data. Takes as
          argument one input value and returns a tuple with the key
          and a value to be reduced.

        reduce_func

          Function to reduce partitioned version of intermediate data
          to final output. Takes as argument a key as produced by
          map_func and a sequence of the values associated with that
          key.

        num_workers

          The number of workers to create in the pool. Defaults to the
          number of CPUs available on the current host.
        """
        self.map_func = map_func
        self.reduce_func = reduce_func
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_workers)

    def partition(self, mapped_values):
        """Organize the mapped values by their key.
        Returns an unsorted sequence of tuples with a key and a sequence of values.
        """
        partitioned_data = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for key, value in mapped_values:
            partitioned_data[key].append(value)
        return partitioned_data.items()

    def __call__(self, inputs, chunksize=1):
        """Process the inputs through the map and reduce functions given.

        inputs
          An iterable containing the input data to be processed.

        chunksize=1
          The portion of the input data to hand to each worker.  This
          can be used to tune performance during the mapping phase.
        """
        map_responses = self.pool.map(self.map_func, inputs, chunksize=chunksize)
        partitioned_data = self.partition(itertools.chain(*map_responses))
        reduced_values = self.pool.map(self.reduce_func, partitioned_data)
        return reduced_values


import multiprocessing
import string

from multiprocessing_mapreduce import SimpleMapReduce

def file_to_words(filename):
    """Read a file and return a sequence of (word, occurances) values.
    """
    STOP_WORDS = set([
            'a', 'an', 'and', 'are', 'as', 'be', 'by', 'for', 'if', 'in', 
            'is', 'it', 'of', 'or', 'py', 'rst', 'that', 'the', 'to', 'with',
            ])
    TR = string.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))

    print multiprocessing.current_process().name, 'reading', filename
    output = []

    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.lstrip().startswith('..'): # Skip rst comment lines
                continue
            line = line.translate(TR) # Strip punctuation
            for word in line.split():
                word = word.lower()
                if word.isalpha() and word not in STOP_WORDS:
                    output.append( (word, 1) )
    return output


def count_words(item):
    """Convert the partitioned data for a word to a
    tuple containing the word and the number of occurances.
    """
    word, occurances = item
    return (word, sum(occurances))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import operator
    import glob

    input_files = glob.glob('*.rst')

    mapper = SimpleMapReduce(file_to_words, count_words)
    word_counts = mapper(input_files)
    word_counts.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    word_counts.reverse()

    print '\nTOP 20 WORDS BY FREQUENCY\n'
    top20 = word_counts[:20]
    longest = max(len(word) for word, count in top20)
    for word, count in top20:
        print '%-*s: %5s' % (longest+1, word, count)


$ python multiprocessing_wordcount.py

PoolWorker-1 reading basics.rst
PoolWorker-3 reading index.rst
PoolWorker-4 reading mapreduce.rst
PoolWorker-2 reading communication.rst

TOP 20 WORDS BY FREQUENCY

process         :    80
starting        :    52
multiprocessing :    40
worker          :    37
after           :    33
poolworker      :    32
running         :    31
consumer        :    31
processes       :    30
start           :    28
exiting         :    28
python          :    28
class           :    27
literal         :    26
header          :    26
pymotw          :    26
end             :    26
daemon          :    22
now             :    21
func            :    20
```